# WiFi issues in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04. Wifi is not at all stable in that. Suddenly it does not connect. At times itc connected to Wifi but the net speed is very very. Wifi is highly unstable.
I googled out many times, ran all scripts but could not find permanent solution.

Additional drivers concept also did not work for me. That broadcom driver was not visible at all for me.

Kindly help me out with a permanent solution

Comment: You can eliminate configuration problems and verify that it's not suspect hardware by testing with the Live CD. I have had a lot of problems with 14.04 (though not with wireless) and I eventually had to upgrade to 14.10 to solve them. If the 14.04 Live CD shows problems, try the 14.10 one, so see whether it's worth upgrading.

Comment: there is not permanent fix for this is it ?? :(

Comment: Because I don't know what the problem is, I can't possibly say if it has been fixed or not. If you try the Live CDs, your observations should allow you to home in on a solution. You could also try proprietary drivers from Broadcom's web site.

Answer (score 1):

I have just attempted to resolve a similar problem.  My issue was that I had spotty wireless using a RTL8192EE wireless card on a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04.

You can see what wireless card you are using by typing "lspci".  It will list a bunch of devices.  In my case, the relevant entry is:
"...Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter"
To better enable other people to help you, it is useful to state what your wireless card is.

The built-in drivers bundled with 14.04 didn't work well for this.  The connection was spotty and would drop after a bit. Also there seems to be computer freezing issues when trying to modify it.

A solution that worked for me was to download appropriate drivers -- I haven't yet been using them for very long so I have yet to see how they hold up on a longer timescale.  I did this by using the code in:
clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver
which is valid for multiple realtek cards.

I found this solution from this answer on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452315/problems-with-realtek-rtl8188ee-on-14-04/468900#468900).

Copying the relevant part from that answer here:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver
cd rtl8188ce-linux-driver
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo cp -r firmware/* /lib/firmware
```